# Node , entity.ts file causes ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. QueryFailedError: could not create unique index

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nest

I encountered this strange error when I added the `{unique: true}` in an entity file's @Column() decorator.

> The code that caused the error are the lines with **@Coulmn({unique: true})**:

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User{
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column({unique: true})
username: string; 

@Column()
password: string; 

@Column({unique: true})
email: string;

}
```

##### The full error description is:

```
The full error description is:
[Nest] 508  - 06/21/2022, 9:08:49 AM   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the 
 database. Retrying (6)...
QueryFailedError: could not create unique index "UQ_78a916df40e02a9deb1c4b75edb"
at PostgresQueryRunner.query (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\piotr-1\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:299:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at PostgresQueryRunner.executeQueries (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\piotr-1\src\query-runner\BaseQueryRunner.ts:609:13)
at PostgresQueryRunner.changeColumn (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\piotr-1\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:2116:9)
at PostgresQueryRunner.changeColumns (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\piotr-1\src\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.ts:2128:13)
at RdbmsSchemaBuilder.updateExistColumns (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\piotr-1\src\schema-builder\RdbmsSchemaBuilder.ts:861:13)        
at RdbmsSchemaBuilder.executeSchemaSyncOperationsInProperOrder (D:\Creation\NestJS\prod\myapp\src\schema-builder\RdbmsSchemaBuilder.ts:215:9)
```

Answer (score 1):

**In my case I had to add the entity in forFeature to the module:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

##### This is what I found out was the cause:

(1) The state of my database was that it had multiple entries with identical values in the 'username' & 'email' columns.

(2) Then when I added the option `{unique: true}` the error appeared.

(3) Conclusion:
It seems that if a db already has duplicate values in a column it causes the introduction of `{unique: true}` to fail with:

`ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database.`

##### How to fix this error

Option 1: Delete the database table, then `{unique: true}` will work.

Option 2: Rename values so that they are unique, then introduce `{unique: true}` and it will work without errors.